# mysql returning 1 row per id

Tags: mysql, sql

I am trying to join 3 tables. I would like to each project one time if it has a post with media in that post.

```
SELECT *
FROM `database`.project join
     post
     on post.project_id = post.id join
     media
     on media.post_id = post.id
```

What i currently get as result

[image]

> Example

I want to code to return one instance of

```
Floaty
HeadPhones
Fasion + Technologie
```

so that it doesn't return multiple projects

Any help would be much appricated

Comment: Which one instance do you want it to return?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT distinct name
FROM database.project join
     post
     on post.project_id = post.id join
     media
     on media.post_id = post.id
```

Comment: Think you just need distinct here - include whatever fields you want

Comment: PS: is there a way to select it and still retail the rest of the information, not only showing the name but also everything related to it with the media and post model's @ Daniel Marcus

Comment: Yes just type out all the fields in your select like this: select distinct name, content, created_date...ect

Answer (score 0):

you can use distinct: select distinct project.id.
https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_distinct.asp

Or you can use group by: group by project.id, project.name...
https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_groupby.asp

Both of then needs to put all the fields results on the query